# Getting Undefined in object literal when the result should be simple

Tags: javascript

So this is super simple stuff but for some reason i cant figure out what i am doing wrong. My hash simply wont return the output of my function. any help would be greatly apperciated

```
myArray = ["firstname lastname", "emailadress"];
var splitName = function(string){ 
    var final_string = string.split(" ");
  console.log(final_string);
};
var result = splitName(myArray[0]);

console.log(result); // this returns undefined 

myData = {
fullName : splitName(myArray[0]), 
};
console.log(myData); //still returns undefined
```

Comment: Your `splitName` function doesn't return anything...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make the function splitName `return final_string;`